# ASP.NET Core MVC: The partial view was not found in a custom feature folder structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have read a nice [article](http://www.hossambarakat.net/2016/02/16/asp-net-core-mvc-feature-folders/) about how I can use feature folder structure in my  ASP.NET Core MVC application. My plan is to use then a feature folder structure to organize my web application in a better way. 
First of all lets see my folder structure:

```
...
wwwroot
Claims
   Controllers
   Services
   Views
      Shared
Map
...
```

I have followed the [article](http://www.hossambarakat.net/2016/02/16/asp-net-core-mvc-feature-folders/) and I implemented the IViewLocationExpander like the following:

```
public class MyViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(MyViewLocationExpander);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        var viewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "/Claims/Views/{0}.cshtml",
            "/Claims/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        return viewLocationFormats;
    }
}
```

I placed my main Claims.cshtml view in the "/Claims/Views/" folder. At the beginning of my Claims.cshtml I have to following line to render my partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_NewClaimPopup");
```

As for the _NewClaimPopup.cshtml, it placed it into the path "/Claims/Views/Shared". But unfortunately I got the following exception when trying to GET the following url: http://localhost:13078/Claims/Claims

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_NewClaimPopup' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Claims/_NewClaimPopup.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_NewClaimPopup.cshtml
```

It seems that the custom paths are successfully added by the implementation of IViewLocationExpander.

Additional infos:

1. What I also tried is to use "~" sign in paths of the implementation of IViewLocationExpander, so:  "~/Claims/Views/{0}.cshtml" and "~/Claims/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" but it does not help.
2. I tried to use absolute path for rendering my partial view, but still nothing

   @Html.Partial(""~/Claims/Views/_NewClaimPopup.cshtml");

And of course, I registered my expander in the Startup.cs:

```
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new MyViewLocationExpander()));
```

Last but not least I attach a picture about my project structure:
[image]

Any other idea? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you registered the Custom location expander in startup ?

Comment: @Rohit Hey Rohit! Thanks for comment. Yes, I have registered it. (I updated my question with it)

Comment: I have tried exactly as per your structure, which is working fine on my end. Is name of your view etc is correct ? Can you share screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: @Rohit 
I just arrived from home, sorry for the late reply. I attached a picture about my project structure.

Comment: @mirind4 it may not be the answer, but I'd re-add the ~ as mentioned in #1. If the article is what you're basing it off of, it leverages it so it should at least put you in the general area.

Comment: @Robert Thanks a lot, the ~ was also necessary to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made sample application. You can download from below link
[Custom View Location](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3r_zMG9Y-HJU1RWYzQ2VG9pbTQ/view)

Comment: thanks for it, i gonna check it when i get home from work ;)

Comment: I got it worked, thanks a lot! The only drawback is that I have to add "@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}" at every beginning of the .cshtml file. Or I place the _Layout.cshtml to every views folder which would be a huge duplication i don't want. Maybe any idea about?

Comment: You need to add _Layout file in your Claims/Shared folder and also add other file _ViewStart.cshtml in Claims folder and give layout reference in that file like below `@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
`

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Sorry for the late reply, i was on vacation...Well, that's what I want to prevent. Now, I have folders like Claims, Containers, ContainerMap, etc. So I would have to add the _Layout file to all the corresponding Shared folder of Claims, Containers, etc...Its a pretty big duplication I think. Right now I have one Shared folder in the Views folder which is next to the feature folders. It seems the best would be to leave this Views/Shared folder as it is. Or any other idea? :)

Comment: Its up to to you, you can keep the default project structure OR to avoid duplication of layout files, you can rename the default `Views` folder name to customized folder name and add all Views in the folder.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now, thanks again for all you help ;)